# How to pass / marshal a struct with a string[] field from C# to C++ library with C bindings?

Tags: c#, c++, string, struct, marshalling

I would like to pass a configuration structure from C# to a library with a C interface (that has a C++ implementation behind the interface).
Below are the .h/.cpp files and the C# code calling into it (this is a small test library).

If I leave out the fields and code for the stringArray, this works fine: all 3 fields are passed nicely, and I can read and use them from the C++ code in the library.

But if I use the strings[] field, I get crashes...

Apart from what's shown in the code below, I then also tried with the following line for the stringArray marshaling, thinking that it might perhaps need to be specified as an "array of pointers to 0-terminated strings", but that doesn't work either:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public string[] stringArray;    // array of arraySize strings
```

MyLib.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct _Config
{
    unsigned long arraySize;
    double* doubleArray;        // array of arraySize doubles
    const char* stringVar;
    const char** stringArray;   // array of arraySize strings as const char*
} Config;

#pragma pack(pop)

__declspec(dllexport) int SetConfig(Config config);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

MyLib.cpp:

```
#include "MyLib.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int SetConfig(Config config)
{
    if (config.arraySize == 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned long N = config.arraySize;
    
    std::vector<double> doubles(N);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < N; i++)
        doubles[i] = config.doubleArray[i];
    
    std::string stringVar = config.stringVar;
    
    std::vector<std::string> strings(N);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < N; i++)
        strings[i] = config.stringArray[i];
    
    return 0;
}
```

MyLib.cs:

```
namespace MySpace
{
    public class MyLib
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
        public struct Config
        {
            public uint arraySize;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] 
            public double[] doubleArray;    // array of arraySize doubles

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string stringVar;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
            public string[] stringArray;    // array of arraySize strings
        }

        public void Test_SetConfig()
        {
            Config config;
            config.arraySize = 3;
            config.doubleArray = new double[3] { 1.11, 2.22, 3.33 };
            config.stringVar = "str";
            config.stringArray = new string[3] { "str 1", "str 2", "str 3" };
            
            int result = MyLibNativeMethods.SetConfig(config);
            
            if (result != 0) 
                throw new Exception("Error in Test_SetConfig");
        }
    }

    public class MyLibNativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("MyLib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int SetConfig(MyLib.Config config);
    }
}
```

So, my question is:

- What am I doing wrong in the code above for marshaling the string[]?
- Is it even possible to marshal a string[] in a struct from C# to C/C++?
- And if not: what's are the alternatives?

Thanks!

Koen

Comment: What about a `nullptr` terminated array?

Comment: Why are you using `pragma pack` and `Pack=1`?

Comment: @Charlieface In this case it's probably not needed, but I do it to be explicit about the struct packing / field alignment, so I can be sure it's the same in the managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: @tadman Not sure I understand what you mean with this. Could you please explain a bit more how you would use a nullptr terminated array to solve it?